# Masstransit Courier Activity problem to catch exception and trigger Compensate

Tags: .net, masstransit, saga

i am trying to work with masstransit courier routing slip. i have fulfill consumer that activates are added as

```
public class FullFillHerdGroupEditConsumer : IConsumer<IFullFillHerdGroupEditMessage>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IFullFillHerdGroupEditMessage> context)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine(" start Fullfill consumer");

            var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());

            

            Console.WriteLine("1 - Global raw data Herd Group Edit Activity");

            builder.AddActivity("GlobalRawDataGroupEdit", new Uri("queue:GlobalGeneticsRawDataEditGroup_execute"), new
            {
                newGroupTitle = context.Message.GroupTitle,
                oldGroupTitle = context.Message.oldGroupTitle
            });




            Console.WriteLine("2 - Global Analytics Herd Group Edit Activity");

            builder.AddActivity("GlobalAnalyticsGroupEdit", new Uri("queue:GlobalAnalyticsEditGroup_execute"), new
            {
                GroupId = context.Message.GroupId,
                GroupTitle = context.Message.GroupTitle,
                oldGroupTitle = context.Message.oldGroupTitle
            });


            var routingSlip = builder.Build();

            await context.Execute(routingSlip);
        }
    }
```

and as mentioned i have two activities.

First activity to execute in fullfill consumer

```
public class GlobalGeneticsRawDataEditGroupActivity : IActivity<IGlobalGeneticsRawDataEditGroupArgument, IGeneticsRawDataEditGroupLog>
{

    public async Task<CompensationResult> Compensate(CompensateContext<IGeneticsRawDataEditGroupLog> context)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine($"[ rawdata ] : Compensate rawdata Edit Group Activity roleback to ( {context.Log.oldGroupTitle} ) from ( {context.Log.newGroupTitle} )");
        return context.Compensated();
    }

    public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<IGlobalGeneticsRawDataEditGroupArgument> context)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine($"[ rawdata ] : Execute rawdata Edit Group Activity Edit to ( {context.Arguments.newGroupTitle} ) from ( {context.Arguments.oldGroupTitle} )");

        //do some logics

        return context.Completed();
    }
}

public interface IGeneticsRawDataEditGroupLog
{
    public string newGroupTitle { get; set; }
    public string oldGroupTitle { get; set; }
}

public interface IGlobalGeneticsRawDataEditGroupArgument
{
    public string newGroupTitle { get; set; }
    public string oldGroupTitle { get; set; }
}
```

and the second one which i want to reproduce exception to observe and test compensation.

```
public async Task<CompensationResult> Compensate(CompensateContext<IGlobalAnalyticsEditGroupLog> context)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine($"[ Global Analytics ] : Compensate Edit Group Activity roleback to ( {context.Log.oldGroupTitle} ) from ( {context.Log.GroupTitle} ) ");
            
            
            return context.Compensated();
        }

        public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<IGlobalAnalyticsEditGroupArgument> context)
        {

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine($"[ Global Analytics ] : Execute Edit Group Activity Edit to ( {context.Arguments.GroupTitle} ) from  ( {context.Arguments.oldGroupTitle} )");

            if (true)
            {
                //throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a Test Exception....!");
                return context.FaultedWithVariables(new InvalidOperationException("This is a Test Exception....!"), new 
                {
                    GroupTitle = context.Arguments.GroupTitle,
                    oldGroupTitle = context.Arguments.oldGroupTitle
                });
            }

            //do some logics

            return context.Completed();
            

            
        }
    }

    public interface IGlobalAnalyticsEditGroupArgument
    {
        
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
        public string oldGroupTitle { get; set; }
        
    }

    public interface IGlobalAnalyticsEditGroupLog
    {
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
        public string oldGroupTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

the problem is throwing exception in activity does not trigger the compensate task that here it shows some message for test with different color.

Note: i also set retries to 2 in masstransit configuration.
and this is what i get 
[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If an activity does not store any compensation data, the Compensate method is never called."

I believe you need to fault the activity with compensation data in order for the Compensate method to be called.

From the documentation: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/courier/activities.html#terminating-a-routing-slip

Maybe something like this [https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/3943#:~:text=return%20context.FaultedWithVariables(new%20System.Exception(%22%E9%94%99%E8%AF%AF%22)%2C%20log](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/3943#:%7E:text=return%20context.FaultedWithVariables(new%20System.Exception(%22%E9%94%99%E8%AF%AF%22)%2C%20log)%3B)

Comment: thank you . return context.Completed<log>(new { log data ..... }); solved my problem. in the end of activity we have to passed the log data so the log data for the activity stored in slip routing and can be compensate if next activity failed. by only return FaultedWithVariales() it wont work so i hope you extend your second sentence.